# How to create specific Date Output as String?

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
public class Period {

   private Date startDate = new Date();
   private String startTime = "10:00";
   private Date endDate = new Date();  
   private String endTime = "23:59";
}
```

Now i need two string outputs "2014-01-08T10:00:00" and "2014-01-08T23:59:00" !

How i can create these two outputs by using the class Period? It is necessary to work with the class Period, which includes startTime and EndTime as Strings!

I only have this small code for using the class SimpleDateFormat:

```
final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
```

Thanks for helping me !

Comment: Use `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'")` and append the string?

Comment: And how "final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'" + "23:59");" creates my necessary string output?

Comment: Use a `Calendar` object for creating `Date` types.

Comment: Sorry but i need a code example, i don´t understand this

Comment: When you `.format` it returns a String. contatenate the `startTime` to the return value of the `.format`

Comment: But method format of class SimpleDateFormat needs a parameter. Sorry but i need a complete code example to understand this

Comment: @tobias_k you should've made it an answer :) +1 for you

Answer (score 2):

What @tobias_k is saying is this. This is your format

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'");
```

When you call `.format` to format the `Date`, it returns a String

```
String dateString = format.format(period.getStartDate());
```

Then concatenate it

```
dateString = dateString + period.getStartTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Using `GregorianCalendar`

```
Date startDate = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");

GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DATE), 10, 00, 00);
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));
```

**Update1**
To get the string value in variable:

```
String str = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
System.out.println(str);
```

Comment: But i need the string value "startTime" and "endTome" in class Period !!

Comment: I guess the answer given by @peeskillet(+1) is more suitable to your question. If you only want to get formatted date and not want to use in other date operations.